# FaceBook app request is shown on website only, but not on FB app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, facebook-app-requests

I'm sending an app request from my iphone app, using this code:

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"Join my app",  @"message", [NSString     stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[filteredContacts objectAtIndex:path] valueForKey:@"id"]] ,@"to",
                               nil];

    [facebook dialog:@"apprequests"
       andParams:params
     andDelegate:self];
```

while  [[filteredContacts objectAtIndex:path] valueForKey:@"id"]  returns a facebook ID value.

When a FB friend of mine gets the request he can see it in the notifications section on his facebook - but only on the website itself.
When trying to find it in the facebook iphone app  - it's just not there. also, it's not found on the mobile site.

How can it be posible that I see the notification on the website only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the answer was very simple - 
I should have define the app as a mobile app when I created it as a FB app.